# I have wrapper class that include a lot of nested object what can I do to set recipient values. I need to create new Instance of class

Tags: apex, rest-api

```apex
public with sharing class UserAPIResponseWrapperClass {
    
    public String recordId{get;set;}
    public String id{get;set;}
    public Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
    public List<Thresholds> thresholds = new List<Thresholds>();
    
    public class Thresholds {
        public List<Actions> actions = new List<Actions>();
    }

    public class Schedule {
        public String frequency = 'monthly';
        public String frequencyType = 'specific';
        public Details details = new Details();
    }

    public class Recipients {
        public String id{get;set;}
        public String type = 'user';
    }

    public class Details {
        public Integer time_Z = 9;
        public List<Integer> daysOfMonth = new List<Integer>{1};
    }

    public class Configuration {
        public List<Recipients> recipients = new List<Recipients>();
    }

    public class Actions {
        public Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    }
```

> 09:38:19:591 USER_DEBUG [55]|DEBUG|Wrapper:
> UserAPIResponseWrapperClass:[id=null, recordId=null,
> schedule=Schedule:[details=Details:[daysOfMonth=(1), time_Z=9],
> frequency=monthly, frequencyType=specific], thresholds=()]

Every time I tried to create instance the thresholds is empty without nested elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's empty because you haven't set it (either in a constructor or in the "client" code, the code where you run `new UserAPIResponseWrapperClass();`).

Making an instance of `List<Threshold>` does not create an instance of `Theshold`.

If you're not deserializing JSON, you'll need to either:

- Replace `public List<Thresholds> thresholds = new List<Thresholds>();` with `public List<Thresholds> thresholds = new List<Thresholds>(new Thresholds());`
- Create an instance of `Thresholds` and add it in your client code, e.g.

  ```
  UserAPIResponseWrapperClass wrapper = new UserAPIResponseWrapperClass();
  // Outside of the wrapper class, you use the outer class name to access
  //   the inner class types.
  wrapper.thresholds.add(new UserAPIResponseWrapperClass.Thresholds());
  ```

You'll need to do something similar for `Thresholds` and `Configuration`.